# Reciprocal of "conformant"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or short phrase to express the reciprocal of "conformant"? For example, if the production processes at my factory are conformant to ISO 9001 standards, then ISO 9001 standards are *(what)* in relation to such production processes?

I would like to avoid nouns that connote the notion of standards, since whatever you conform to may not be a standard at all. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try http://thesaurus.com/browse/conformant ?

Comment: _(Be) conformant (to)_ is the predicate with the adjective form, _(be) (in) conformance (with)_ is the predicate with the nominal form, and _conform (to)_ is the predicate with the verb root. They mean the same thing, but have different uses. As @Josh61 suggests, _accord_ works nicely here: note _accordant, accordance, accord (with)_. Another possibility is imply a causational action link: the standards might be said to _control, guide,_ or* define_ your production processes.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Are you saying that, in my example, if the processes are conformant to the standard, then the standard is *accordant* to the processes? That sounds more like a synonym to me, rather than an opposite relationship. Your second option sounds better though. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a non-gerund adjective that describes this, but perhaps *governing* (or [one of its synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/govern), like *dictating*) or *defining* would work?

> The ISO 9001 standards *are defining* our production processes.
>
> The company policy *is governing* our behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is any such word.  Here are two attempts...

> ISO 9001 standards ***guide*** or ***dictate*** or ***circumscribe*** or ***constrain*** our production processes.
>
> ISO 9001 standards ***are satisfied by*** or ***are adhered to by*** or ***are conformed to by*** our production processes.

The trouble, of course, is that many of these terms are too loose or too loaded with other connotations.  In the right context, constrain might work because it has a fairly neutral meaning in technical contexts (e.g., 'mathematical constraint').

Answer (score 0):

What about *Accordant*,

accordant 
adj
1. (and foll by: with) in conformity or harmony
acˈcordantly adv

Collins English Dictionary –

Comment: But *accordant* isn't the "reciprocal" (opposite meaning) of *conformant!* It's effectively just a far less common ***synonym***.

Comment: Reciprocal is the wrong word, not my answer. Reading the sentence it is clear he is looking for synonym.

Comment: Actually in Spanish "reciproco" means "relative to" and unlike English has no reference to something which is contrary. OP was taken in by the words similarity I guess.

Comment: No, I am not looking for a synonym but for a complementary word. I understand that "reciprocal" means precisely that; see e.g. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocal

Answer (score 0):

Why not **[criterion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/criterion)** (or *criteria* if there are multiple elements in the test)

> A principle or standard by which something may be judged or decided:
>   the launch came too close to violating safety criteria